# mariaDB service stopped by windows

Tags: windows, mariadb, innodb

errors as follows:

InnoDB:Failed to find tablespace for table 'mysql'.'gtid_slave_pos' in the cache. Attempting.

InnoDB:Refusing to load '.\mysql\gtid_slave_pos.ibd'(id=3,flags=0x21);dictionary contains id=3,flags=0

InnoDB:Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/gtid_slave_pos'.

Comment: What version?  Did you recently upgrade?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: windows server 2008,10.2.11-mariadb, was moved from another windows server about a month ago. Did not upgrade recently.